# Converting Numpy Array after cropping image

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently using this code:

```
def bundle_contour(image):
    src_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    crop_img = cv2.resize(src_gray, (196, 196))
    v = np.median(crop_img)
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - 0.33) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + 0.33) * v))
    filter = cv2.bilateralFilter(src_gray, 9, 75, 75)
    filter = filter.astype(np.uint8)
    edged = cv2.Canny(filter, lower, upper)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
    thresh = cv2.dilate(edged, kernel, iterations=2)

    # Find contours in threshold image, then grab the largest one
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Find the extreme points
    extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

    # crop new image out of the original image using the four extreme points (left, right, top, bottom)
    new_image = image[extTop[1]:extBot[1], extLeft[0]:extRight[0]]
    return new_image

def load_data(filename):
    image = cv2.imread(filename)
    # crop the bundle and ignore the unnecessary rest part of the image
    cnt_image = bundle_contour(image)
    # resize image
    resized_image = cv2.resize(cnt_image, dsize=(196, 196), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    # normalize values
    norm_image = resized_image / 255.
    reshaped_img = norm_image.reshape(196,196,1)
    return reshaped_img

def compose_dataset(df):
    data = []
    labels = []

    for img_path, label in df.values:
        data.append(load_data(img_path))
        labels.append(label)

    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

X_train, y_train = compose_dataset(train_df)
print('Train data shape: {}, Labels shape: {}'.format(X_train.shape, y_train.shape))
```

I get this error:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 115248 into shape (196,196,1).

If I change the code to `norm_image.reshape(196,196,-1)`, my output is:

```
Train data shape: (134, 196, 196, 3), Labels shape: (134,)
```

How can I get the shape to be (196,196,1) for the input into my CNN??

Comment: Does your CNN use grayscale images? Then, simply convert your image to grayscale. Your current input seems to have dimensions of `(196, 196, 3)` (since `196 * 196 * 3 = 115248`). The error message here is quite precise.

Answer (score 0):

@HansHirse is compeletely right. I'm writing an answer to make it more specific.

Most probably the error is caused by `load_data` method. Since you are reading the image but not converting to the grayscale.

Therefore you need to add the sentence

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.BGR2GRAY)
```

to the `load_data`. So the correct code will be:

```py
def load_data(filename):
    image = cv2.imread(filename)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # crop the bundle and ignore the unnecessary rest part of the image
    cnt_image = bundle_contour(image)
    # resize image
    resized_image = cv2.resize(cnt_image, dsize=(196, 196), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    # normalize values
    norm_image = resized_image / 255.
    reshaped_img = norm_image.reshape(196,196,1)
    return reshaped_img
```

If you are using `bundle_contour` function after the `load_data`, then there is no need for the sentence:

```py
src_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

You can remove it.